# Setting up JBoss EAP 6.0 on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-juno, jboss-eap-6

I just wanted to confirm whether there is a substantial difference between the following two scenarios:

1. Create a new JBoss EAP 6.0 server instance from Eclipse using
   Create->New Server.
2. Setting up a standalone JBoss EAP 6.0 server and
   then linking it to Eclipse using JBoss Tools.

It would be a great help if you could throw some light on it, I've been stuck on this for a while.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have JBoss Tools installed according to [Matrix of supported platforms, runtimes and technologies in JBossTools & JBDS](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MatrixOfSupportedPlatformsRuntimesAndTechnologiesInJBossToolsJBDS) you will always need to set up a standalone instance.

I don't have Juno lying around anymore, but I think that if you follow through with "Create->New Server" the wizard is going to ask you to browse to the directory of an existing JBoss installation.

Comment: Correct. I don't see any difference between point 1 and 2 mentioned in the question :s

Comment: Plus 1 for the link to the Matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "link it to Eclipse" is the same as "Create->New Server".  Here's how to do that even though you didn't ask for explicit steps. (This question leads me to think there is a fundamental misunderstanding so I'm spelling it out.)

1. Install the software in /www/jboss/server (or wherever) Set it up
   (edit standalone.xml or whatever).
2. Open eclipse. Create->New Server.
3. Select JBoss Enterprise Middleware then whichever version you are
   using.
4. In the next window where it says home directory, you will enter the name of the directory from step 1.

"Creating a server" in eclipse is creating a graphical interface to the actual server you installed.  It's great because you an manage many aspects of the server (NOT configuring standalone.xml) from within eclipse. You can start and stop it and deploy to it.